# Sharing sessions between ASP.NET Web Forms application and Blazor application

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, blazor

Here is the story,

The framework version for our ecommerce site, which was created with asp.net(vb.net), is 4.7.2. This current application will be changed to a blazor application (7.0). We employ the incremental conversion strategy, which means that until the asp.net program is completely transformed into a blazor app, two apps will be operating. Assume we used Blazor to transform some pages. In the current asp.net application, sessions are used, for instance, session("OrderId"). I also want to access or modify the value of the Blazor application's session("OrderId") variable.

I tried to follow the instruction, but I was unable to make it work in my applications (the sharing session section of the tutorial is a little different from my situation).- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-from-asp-net-to-asp-net-core-part-4/.

Since this github application is extremely comparable to our website, you can look at it.
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnBlazor/tree/main/src
To switch to eShopOnBlazor from eShopLegacyWebForms. How can sessions be shared between the two projects?

Is there anyone have an idea how to share sessions between ASP.NET webforms and a Blazor application?

Comment: "We have an issue that needs to be resolved before starting, it is about session sharing between the two projects." isn't very informative.  Can you provide an example of what you want to share and how?

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Hi, the comment was as a Blazor topic reviewer.  My webforms knowledge is too rusty to answer your question.